# Can es be abbreviated as 's at the beginning of a sentence?

Tags: colloquial, contractions

In colloquial speech I have often found the word *es* contracted as *'s*, but usually attached to a previous word, for example:

> Gibt's noch Fragen?

But can it only be used in that context, or can it also be contracted this way at the beginning of a sentence or clause, for example:

> Ich glaub, 's war nur ein Witz.

> 'S ist Viertel nach zehn.

This is for a translation of a computer game in which some of the characters' speech is much less proper than others; the English is written as if they are dropping numerous letters and using bad grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Ich glaub, 's war nur ein Witz.

This is okay if you want to mark it as non-stilted speech. But I have to disappoint you. You can't mark a character as *someone who speaks less properly* that way. As we all speak like that, even seasoned authors.

> <strike>'S ist Viertel nach zehn.</strike>

This is not how people speak. They instead say

> Ist Viertel nach zehn.

Spoken German allows dropping the topic. We do that all the time in speech.

Comment: So I can leave out the es at the beginning of a sentence, but can I do so at the beginning of a clause, i.e. "ich glaub, war nur ein Witz?"

Comment: That's possible but less likely because of the rhythm.

Comment: Konfuzius sagt: "S'is, wie's is"

Comment: What you might hear is "War nur ein Witz, glaub ich."

Comment: Ich würde sogar sagen, dass "Is' Viertel nach Zehn" gebräuchlicher im Gesprochenen ist als das ausgesprochene 't' von 'ist'.

Comment: Ich würde es ungefähr "hss Viertel nach Zehn" aussprechen. Das i verschwindet auch so gut wie komplett, das s ist aber etwas länger und "aspiriert".

Answer (score 3):

Yes, *»es«* can be abbreviated at the beginning of a sentence, but you have to write the remaining letter in lower case.

> »Wie ist das Wetter?«
> »'s regnet.«
> »Und was brauchst du?«
> »'s fehlt an allem.«

[image]